# Gnuplot pointinterval does not work

Tags: gnuplot

I have an issue using the command `pointinterval` on gnuplot.

E.g. the following minimal example

```
plot test.dat with linespoints pi -1
```

with test.dat being

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

does not work properly. The outcome is as follows:

```
gnuplot> plot "test.dat" with linespoints pi -1
                                          ^
         ';' expected
```

I have no clue why it won't work

Comment: That doesn't work because you gnuplot version doesn't yet support this feature. I don't know when it was introduced, but it works at least since 4.6.5.

Comment: The `pointinterval` option was introduced in version 4.4.0.

Comment: thanks :-) it works just fine with an updated version